# Selfhosted supabase realtime image not able to connect to DB

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-realtime

When I run the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: supabase/postgres:14.1.0.105
    container_name: realtime-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./dev/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: /var/run/postgresql
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  realtime:
    depends_on:
      - db
    #build: .
    image: supabase/realtime:v2.22.5
    container_name: realtime-server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      PORT: 4000
      DB_HOST: host.docker.internal
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      DB_NAME: postgres
      DB_ENC_KEY: supabaserealtime
      DB_AFTER_CONNECT_QUERY: 'SET search_path TO _realtime'
      API_JWT_SECRET: dc447559-996d-4761-a306-f47a5eab1623
      FLY_ALLOC_ID: fly123
      FLY_APP_NAME: realtime
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: UpNVntn3cDxHJpq99YMc1T1AQgQpc8kfYTuRgBiYa15BLrx8etQoXz3gZv1/u2oq
      ERL_AFLAGS: -proto_dist inet_tcp
      ENABLE_TAILSCALE: "false"
      DNS_NODES: "''"
    command: sh -c "/app/bin/migrate && /app/bin/realtime eval 'Realtime.Release.seeds(Realtime.Repo)' && /app/bin/server"
```

I get an error:

```
Recreating realtime-server ... done
Attaching to realtime-db, realtime-server
realtime-db | 
realtime-db | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
realtime-db | 
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.017 UTC [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.062 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.062 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.062 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.069 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.077 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-05 16:25:23 UTC
realtime-server | Setting RLIMIT_NOFILE to 100000
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.083 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.084 UTC [35] LOG:  TimescaleDB background worker launcher connected to shared catalogs
realtime-db |  2023-09-05 16:38:00.085 UTC [37] LOG:  pg_cron scheduler started
realtime-server | 16:38:00.673 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.137.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:00.673 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.136.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:03.166 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.136.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:03.440 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.137.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:07.352 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.136.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:07.736 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.137.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
realtime-server | 16:38:15.660 [error] Could not create schema migrations table. This error usually happens due to the following:
realtime-server | 
realtime-server |   * The database does not exist
realtime-server |   * The "schema_migrations" table, which Ecto uses for managing
realtime-server |     migrations, was defined by another library
realtime-server |   * There is a deadlock while migrating (such as using concurrent
realtime-server |     indexes with a migration_lock)
realtime-server | 
realtime-server | To fix the first issue, run "mix ecto.create".
realtime-server | 
realtime-server | To address the second, you can run "mix ecto.drop" followed by
realtime-server | "mix ecto.create". Alternatively you may configure Ecto to use
realtime-server | another table and/or repository for managing migrations:
realtime-server | 
realtime-server |     config :realtime, Realtime.Repo,
realtime-server |       migration_source: "some_other_table_for_schema_migrations",
realtime-server |       migration_repo: AnotherRepoForSchemaMigrations
realtime-server | 
realtime-server | The full error report is shown below.
realtime-server | 
realtime-server | ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available and request was dropped from queue after 14993ms. This means requests are coming in and your connection pool cannot serve them fast enough. You can address this by:
realtime-server | 
realtime-server |   1. Ensuring your database is available and that you can connect to it
realtime-server |   2. Tracking down slow queries and making sure they are running fast enough
realtime-server |   3. Increasing the pool_size (although this increases resource consumption)
realtime-server |   4. Allowing requests to wait longer by increasing :queue_target and :queue_interval
realtime-server | 
realtime-server | See DBConnection.start_link/2 for more information
realtime-server | 
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:932: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
realtime-server |     (elixir 1.14.3) lib/enum.ex:1658: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:1024: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_ddl/4
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:696: Ecto.Migrator.verbose_schema_migration/3
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:510: Ecto.Migrator.lock_for_migrations/4
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:422: Ecto.Migrator.run/4
realtime-server |     (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:146: Ecto.Migrator.with_repo/3
realtime-server |     nofile:1: (file)
realtime-server exited with code 1
```

Does anyone know what's causing it?

Comment: Hey @ventsyv, I am from the supabase team and the Realtime team asked you to create an issue on: 

https://github.com/supabase/realtime

They will help you there and post an answer here once this is resolved.